# Rewriting this matrix expression involving the trace operator

Tags: matrices, trace

Let's assume the minimum necessary conditions for the following expression to be well-defined:
$$-\frac{1}{2} \mbox{Tr} \left(\Sigma^{-1}\left(\Lambda+\Phi -\Psi W- W\Psi^\intercal+W(\Xi+V^{-1})W^\intercal \right)\right)$$

where $\mbox{Tr} (\cdot)$ is the trace of a matrix.

Is there any way to rewrite the above expression as

$$-\frac{1}{2}Tr\left(g(\Sigma^{-1})+f(\Sigma^{-1},W)\right)$$

where $$f(\Sigma^{-1},W)= B_{W\Sigma} A_{\Sigma}^{-1}B_{W\Sigma}^\intercal C_{\Sigma}^{-1}$$

meaning, $B$ is a matrix expression depending on  $W$ and $\Sigma$, and $A$ and $C$ cannot depend on $W$.

Comment: Are all the matrices square?

Comment: @VasilyMitch Yes ;)

Comment: I believe it's impossible unless $\Xi + V^{-1}=-\Phi$